# Self bounty - what happens after bounty period in this scenario

Tags: discussion

I have started a bounty on a question where I have posted an answer. After bounty period,  what happens if my answer had more up votes than all other answers?

Comment: Just **Wait and watch**.

Comment: The same happens as if you take out an ad in the newspaper looking for help taking down a tree, but you ultimately decide to do the job yourself.